# How to add table row with input text inside the table field

Tags: javascript, html

How to add a table row with a text input inside the table field?

```
var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var rowCount = table.row.length;
var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML += "<td class='align-center'>1</td>";
cell2.innerHTML += "<input type='text' class='input-long' name='newcategoryname' value='New Category' onfocus='if(this.value == \"New Category\"){ this.value = \"\"; }' onblur='if(this.value==\"\"){this.value=\"New Category\";}'/>";
```

Comment: check this line : `var rowCount = table.row.length` does it give you anything?

Comment: What you have there works ok in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qj4RW/ The only difference is table.row.length becomes table.rows.length. (Learn to use a Javascript console to view and trace errors--it's a huge help.)

Comment: @struthersneil it works ok there, but why it doesn't work on my script?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create input element by using **createElement** method,
try this

```
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

Comment: is working, but how to set class style and this

value='New Category' onfocus='if(this.value == \"New Category\"){ this.value = \"\"; }' onblur='if(this.value==\"\"){this.value=\"New Category\";}'

into it?

Comment: on element you can set all those